# How to access root privileges in terminal via KVM when passwords are disabled?

Tags: networking, server, permissions, kvm-virtualization

I have locked myself out of my server it seems by screwing up my firewall rules. Luckily I have KVM access... However I have disabled passwords on the root user. I have access to one standard user.

Is it possible to be able to access my root user for this server? Pass the public key in somehow? (clutching at straws!!)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. Do you have physical access to the server? If so I'd hook up a monitor and keyboard, and boot into emergency mode if possible. (Add a "1" no quotes to the end of the kernel line.) This should allow you to enter the password of any user with sudo permissions, even if the root user password is disabled.

Then, you can edit the firewall config file if you need to.

If you don't have a user with sudo on the server or access to the physical server, I don't know how to help.

Comment: Hum interestingly I don't believe I ever had a password set for root. Or rather to say, the one that was given to me was so long ago that I actually have no idea what that could be. But the KVM is basically a physical keyboard and mouse via the browser.

Comment: Ah, the booting into emergancy mode I think I cannot do with the KVM sadly